# Does an SSD just fit into a notebook?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, laptop

Does anybody know if I can upgrade my notebook hard drive to an SSD? Can I put an [**Intel 510 Series Elm Crest SSD**](http://www.cyberport.de/?DEEP=3302-01J&APID=4) into an [**ASUS X7BSV-TY074V**](http://www.notebooksbilliger.de/asus+x7bsv+ty074v+wireless+display) notebook?

Comment: Do you have an OS to install onto this SSD?

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, yes. As long as it's a SATA connection and your notebook has space for a standard 2.5" drive then you should be fine. It's important to note, however, that the new drive won't have an OS on it and may not be formatted with the correct filesystem for whatever OS you'll be using it for (ntfs, hfs+, ext4, etc.).

Comment: In other words: you can do this, but the computer won't boot up until you install windows (and all your apps) again from scratch.

Comment: Clone the existing drive onto the new one.  Don't be surprised if you have to reactivate some programs after doing this.  Windows has brains enough to realize this was just a drive upgrade but not everything does.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to, provided that the replacement is 2.5 inches. You;ll also need to check that your current hard drive is SATA (i.e. not IDE/SCSI) as the one in the link is a SATA drive.